# Unable to catch all mouse co-ordinates when moving mouse faster

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the below code to calculate mouse moved co-ordinates

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  console.log(e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY);
});
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5L7T/1/) is the fiddle​.

My Question is, when I move mouse slowly I am able to see all the mouse moved co-ordinates in console. But when I move faster I could not see all. Only few are counted.Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: No, probably I the ticks just are too slow to register all mouse movements if they are too fast. But you could calculate the line between two coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to intrapolate them (i.e. calculate the points in between yourselves). The browser will just return the mouse position at every new tick (e.g. every 0.01 second).

Happily, the mouse position is only checked every so often, otherwise the OS would immediately freeze.

Intrapolation could look like

```
var posX, posY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  var points = [];
  if(posX && posY) {
      // calculate a straight line that the mouse moved over
      // It gets more difficult if you want to take e.g. 
      // the current curved path into account
      var diffX = e.pageX - posX;
      var diffY = e.pageY - poxY;
      var length = Math.round(Math.sqrt((diffY*diffY)+(diffX*diffX)));
      for(n=0;n<length;n++) {
          var pointX = posX + (n/length) * diffX;
          var pointY = posY + (n/length) * diffY;
          points.push({x:pointX,y:pointY});
      }
  }
  points.push({x:e.pageX,y:e.pageY});
  posX = e.pageX;
  poxY = e.pageY;
  for(point in points) {
      console.log(point.x + ", " + point.y);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide any example on "You will need to intrapolate them (i.e. calculate the points in between yourselves)".

Comment: added an example implementation to answer!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time. But I could not see the difference :-(

Comment: You should do the 1,2,3 and 4 yourself. And of course log the points that you calculate. It's not that difficult :-)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't have much idea on this concept. It would be a resource to learn if you can provide some information on implementing them.

Comment: So I wrote it all out for you... Still you could really do this yourself without much deep thinking. You understand what's going on, right?

Answer (score 1):

No. That's the designed behavior of the OS. It's not the browser's fault; the browser gives you only what it gets from the OS.